# React + typescript + Redux connect function not working

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am kind of new with using Typescript in React. I tried to connect my Redux with my container component, but for some reason it keeps giving me type errors. I have gone through many stack overflow posts but still cannot understand what is happening.

My redux tpes file:

```
export interface StoreState {
    languageName: string,
    enthusiasmLevel: number
}
```

My container component file:

```
// React imports
import React from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../../redux/actions/actions';
import { StoreState } from '../../redux/types/types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';

interface NavbarComponentProps {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel?: number;
  onIcrement?: () => void;
  onDecrement?: () => void;
}

interface DispatchFromProps {
  onDecrement: () => void,
  onIncrement: () => void
}
interface StateFromProps {
  name: string,
  enthusiasmLevel: number
}

type Props = StateFromProps & DispatchFromProps & NavbarComponentProps;

class NavbarContainer extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

  public static defaultProps = {
    enthusiamsLevel: 1
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        navbar works.

        <Link to='/'>left nav</Link>

{/*         
       <p>Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(this.props.enthusiasmLevel)} </p> */}

      <button onClick={this.props.onDecrement}> - </button>
      <button onClick={this.props.onIcrement}> + </button>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ enthusiasmLevel, languageName}: StoreState) {
  return {
    enthusiasmLevel,
    name: languageName
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.EnthusiamsAction>) {
  return {
    onDecrement: () => dispatch(actions.decrementEnthusiasm()),
    onIncrement: () => dispatch(actions.incrementEnthusiasm())
  }
}

export default connect<StateFromProps, DispatchFromProps, NavbarComponentProps, StoreState>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavbarContainer);
```

My error:
[image]

I am guessing that there is a problem with resetting the languageName to name, however even changing that didn't help.

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant signature is the following

```
<TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
    mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
    mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
)
```

When omitting the last `State` it defaults to `{}`.

You should be calling `connect<StateFromProps, DispatchFromProps, NavbarContainerProps, StoreState>(...)(...)`. Think `connect<ReduxInjected, DispatchInjected, GivenByParentWhenUsingThisComponent, ReduxStoreType>`.

Notice I changed the interface a bit, your `Props` should be `NavbarContainerProps` and only include the props that are passed in manually (not from the store).

Then I like to write a type alias `type Props = StateFromProps & DispatchFromProps & NavbarContainerProps;` which you use for defining the component.

```
class NavbarContainer extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 


I updated the signature to mix all the props together. Thank you for that it's a nice trick

type Props = StateFromProps & DispatchFromProps & NavbarComponentProps;
class NavbarContainer extends React.Component<Props, {}> {}


I am afraid I do not really get the issue with the connect. I changed my code a little, but I am still unsure about how to put in the parameters after the signature definition.

export default connect<StateFromProps, DispatchFromProps, NavbarComponentProps, StoreState>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavbarContainer);

Comment: When the 4th generic type parameter was omitted (StoreState) it defaulted to an empty object. `mapStateToProps` is a function from `StoreState` to `StateFromProps` but because that 4th parameter was missing, it was trying to type check as a function from `{}` to `StateFromProps` which is where that error came from.